# How to change cursor on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, cursor

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I do not know how to change the cursor theme. Any answers would help.

Comment: Install `tweak tool`

Answer (score 7):

Install the `gnome tweak tool` launch it and change the cursor from there:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

In the `Appearance tab` make your changes. Also to add custom icons to use with your cursor simple down and extract it to the `~/.icons` directory then `gnome-tweak-tool` should pick it up, and a restart may be required.

### Update:

The package name has changed, so we now do

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

[image]

Comment: I mean how to add a custom cursor, for example, one from the Internet.

Comment: @NTre Download the archive from the internet and extract to your `~/.icons/` directory.

Comment: Please make you question very explicit I have updated my answer...

Comment: It changed to "sudo apt install gnome-tweaks"